TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore') VueJS
I am trying to render a list of items in my NuxtJS application.
<Loading v-if="products.items.length === 0" />
<template v-else>
  <Product v-for="product in products.items" :product="product" />
</template>

and I get the error of

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')

But if I replace the template tag with a div the error will be gone. 
What can be the reason for that?

Needs to be debugged, there can be various reasons

template does not generate any DOM element in itself, hence there is probably a difference between the server-side and client-side code.
There is indeed the need for such a tag on the server because insertBefore is not available on the server.

I believe this can be more complicated, it's not evident the problem is specific to server side. Generally the error means there's a race condition and the element that was expected to be there is not there, it's rather common with v-if/v-for due to how they work

@EstusFlask hm? I don't think I experienced those a lot but maybe you're right. Since OP has a working solution when replacing it with a div, it made sense to me that there is no more to it than the server part of things.
